# Help with wrapping a command line tool in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, wrapper

I'm really stuck with a problem I'm hoping someone can help me with. I'm trying to create a wrapper in Python3.1 for a command line program called `spooky`. I can successfully run this program on the command line like this:

```
$ spooky -a 4 -b .97
```

My first Python wrapper attempt for spooky looked like this:

```
import subprocess

start = "4"
end = ".97"

spooky_path = '/Users/path/to/spooky'
cmd = [spooky_path, '-a', start, '-b', end]
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
print('Done')
```

The above code prints `Done`, but does not execute the program `spooky`

Next I tried to just execute the program on the command line like this:

```
$ /Users/path/to/spooky -a 4 -b .97
```

The above code also fails, and provides no helpful errors.

My question is: How can I get Python to run this program by sending `spooky -a 4 -b .97` to the command line? I would VERY much appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First you have to investigate why the latter commandline call does not work. Unless you did not fix that problem, you do not have to think about your python approach. What are the "helpfull errors" your command line call produces ?

Comment: ...so it runs when you just type in `spooky`, but doesn't when you give it the full path...obvious reason is that the full path is wrong.

Comment: Check if that's actually the right path by comparing it to `which spooky`.

Comment: On an unrelated note, I think that [`subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)  would be more obvious than `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: @Gerret yes, it runs on the command line when typing either `spooky` or  `spooky -a 4 -b .97`. If I type the full path it also works, BUT if i type the full path with arguments it DOES NOT work ('/Users/path/to/spooky -a 4 -b .97')

Comment: @delnan yes, I verified it is the correct path. This is strange! I am also using the absolute path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to drop the stdout=subprocess.PIPE. Doing that disconnects the stdout of your process from Python's stdout and makes it retrievable using the Popen.communicate() function, like so:

```
import subprocess

spooky_path = 'ls'
cmd = [spooky_path, '-l']
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()[0]
print "Output:", output
process.wait()
print('Done')
```

To make it print directly you can use it without the stdout argument:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

Or you can use the call function:

```
process = subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Comment: Wow, this actually works!!! I'm not really sure I understand why your code works considering I was having trouble with the command tool alone? In any case, thank you VERY much for the help.

Comment: It was probably working beforehand, you just didn't see the output because it was piped and you weren't displaying it or even attempting to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your command into a single string:

```
cmd = 'spooky_path -a start -b end'
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

Comment: This will just tell you there's no executable `"spooky_path -a start -b end"`.

Comment: Unfortunately, once the program is working, I will need to use Python to run this commands repeatedly with different `-b` values.

Comment: That isn't a problem even if it has to be a single string, simply interpolate the desired values into the string, e.g.,  `cmd = "spooky -a %s -b %s" % (a, b)` BTW, yes, a single string should work: from the docs: "args should be a string, or a sequence of program arguments. The program to execute is normally the first item in the args sequence or the string if a string is given."

Comment: Well, it doesn't for me - `Popen("touch this")` raises `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'touch this'`, while `Popen(["touch", "this"])` works as expected. Python version 3.2 and 2.7.

Comment: @delnan:  Using a single string works for me if I set `shell=True`.  Answer updated.